# Control other apps music playing from inside my app?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Inside my app I'd like to have a control to `stop/play`, `skipToNext` and  `goToPrevious` song if any other app is already playing music. Similar to what the control-center does already, but I wand those buttons to be available inside my app.

I've seen that `MPMusicPlayerController` allows that for the Apple Music app using `skipToPreviousItem()`, `skipToBeginning()`, `skipToNextItem()`. But I'm looking for a solution that would work for any other app (SoundCloud, Spotify, Deezer, ...), similarly as the control-center does.

Is there any way to control other apps music playing from inside my app?

Comment: In a word, no. Sandboxing will prevent you from *directly* accessing apps not in *your* app group. Now, if said app has an API....

Comment: I'm aware of Sandboxing. But playing music uses shared resources and there's some support to it on a system level. For example, I can check whether there's anything playing by using `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying`. I was hoping for something like next / stop / previous as it can be seen in control center, if you swipe up from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Keep in mind, *everything* you've mentioned (`MPMusicPlayerController`, `AVAudioSession`, "Apple Music", and "control center") are all from Apple - who makes the OS you are programming against. This meets my personal test of "show me" - show me another app out there that can do what you wish to do. Unless these third party apps, working within the constraints of iOS sandboxing, open up their sandboxes to you - deep linking, API, whatever - I don't think you'll be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two potential workarounds:
A) There is a `Spotify App Remote SDK` now https://github.com/spotify/ios-app-remote-sdk#sptappremoteuserapi. You can use that to control the Spotify app directly.

B) If you can live with only controlling `stop/play` you can take over the audio session which will stop Spotify and then end your session hoping that Spotify will automatically resume.